# Create json string for each row in data frame

Tags: r

I have a loop that creates a json string for each column in a data frame in order to store this data as text in a separate database. I would prefer a non-loop method, but I keep running into problems. What is a more efficient way to do this?

```
library(tidyverse)
library(jsonlite)
df <- tibble(id1 = paste('ID',1:10),
       id2 = paste('ID',1:10))
for(r in 1:nrow(df)) {
  df[r,'combo'] <- toJSON(df[r,])
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option with `pmap`

```
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)
df %>%
     mutate(combo = pmap(., ~toJSON(c(...))))
```

Comment: That works! Thanks for the quick response. I figured there was some sort of mapping function but I have a hard time figuring them out.